# Máscara Jquery para moeda real

Tags: jquery

Estou usando esta máscara:

$(".real").mask('#.##0,00', {reverse: true});

Há alguns inputs que recebem alguns cáculos, como esse:

```js
    $('#vd_ga').on('blur',function(){
     var vd_ga = $('#vd_ga').val().replace(',', '.');
     var pvm_ga = $('#pvm_ga').val();
     
     $('#vm_ga').val(vd_ga * pvm_ga);
     $('#eam_ga').val(vd_ga * pvm_ga);
     
    }); 

    $('#pvm_ga').on('blur',function(){
     var vd_ga = $('#vd_ga').val().replace(',', '.');
     var pvm_ga = $('#pvm_ga').val();
    
     
     $('#vm_ga').val(vd_ga * pvm_ga);
     $('#eam_ga').val(vd_ga * pvm_ga);

    });
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-3 col-md-3 canais_titulo">
    Google Adwords
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-2 col-md-2">
    <input name="vd_ga" id="vd_ga" class="real input_geral" type="text" />
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-2 col-md-2">
    <input name="pvm_ga" id="pvm_ga" class="input_geral_2" type="text" /><span class="canais_titulo"> dias</span>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-2 col-md-2">
    <input name="vm_ga" id="vm_ga" class="real input_geral" type="text" readonly />
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-2 col-md-3">
    <input name="eam_ga" id="eam_ga" class="real input_geral_2" type="text" /><span class="canais_titulo"> Cliques</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Mas se, por exemplo eu fizer 90,00 vezes 2, vai dar 180.
E a máscara esta no dois inputs com valor.
Tenho que fazer algo mais para que a máscara funcione corretamente?

Comment: Não está claro qual plugin de mascara você está usando (editei sua pergunta e coloquei uma opção, confira se está correto). Fora isso não está claro qual o problema

Comment: Nossa, esqueci. É o <script type="text/javascript" src="../js/jQuery-Mask-Plugin/dist/jquery.mask.min.js"></script>. O problema é que era para dar 180,00 e não 80, pois, no exemplo são 90,00 x 2 = 180,00

Answer (score 1):

Talvez a melhor opção seja utilizar o método [**toLocaleString**](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toLocaleString)

```js
$(".real").mask('#.##0,00', {
  reverse: true
});

$('#vd_ga, #pvm_ga').on('blur', calculateValue);

function calculateValue() {
  var vd_ga = $('#vd_ga').val().replace(',', '.');
  var pvm_ga = $('#pvm_ga').val();

  $('#vm_ga').val(convertToCurrency(vd_ga * pvm_ga));
  $('#eam_ga').val(convertToCurrency(vd_ga * pvm_ga));
}

function convertToCurrency(value) {
  return value.toLocaleString("pt-BR", {
    style: "currency",
    currency: "BRL",
    minimumFractionDigits: 2
  })
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.mask/1.14.13/jquery.mask.js"></script>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-3 col-md-3 canais_titulo">
    Google Adwords
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-2 col-md-2">
    <input name="vd_ga" id="vd_ga" class="real input_geral" type="text" />
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-2 col-md-2">
    <input name="pvm_ga" id="pvm_ga" class="input_geral_2" type="text" /><span class="canais_titulo"> dias</span>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-2 col-md-2">
    <input name="vm_ga" id="vm_ga" class="real input_geral" type="text" readonly />
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-2 col-md-3">
    <input name="eam_ga" id="eam_ga" class="real input_geral_2" type="text" /><span class="canais_titulo"> Cliques</span>
  </div>
</div>
```